# Chrome extension getdocumentbyid

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want execute a function when i click on a button, for chrome extension, we can't use onclick, so i use
`document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", test);`
but the log says "null" and when i do
`console.log(document.getElementById('myBtn'));`
the log says "null". I don't understand. Obviously my button have "myBtn" in id.

Comment: [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)

Comment: No, I want access to extension page

Comment: You probably declared the script before `<body>` tag. Move the declaration down, right before the closing `</body>` tag. Or use DOMContentLoaded event in your script. Anyway, this is as much as I can guess without seeing the actual code and html.